# regarding installation of MarkLogic server

Tags: marklogic

After installing the MarkLogic server...and make all security changes. But after  reloading the page authentication was popped out. I gave all my credentials but it still popping out and the server page is loaded. Please tell me how to resolve this and also tell me how to change the password of server?

Comment: Which version of MarkLogic? Which OS?

Comment: are you navigating localhost:8001, while this credential popup appears?

Answer (score 4):

As part of the install, you provide credentials for an initial admin yourself. Enter those. Don't enter your own OS credentials. Once you regained access to the Admin ui, you can use that to create more users, and change passwords on that host.

In the event you cannot recover the credentials, and assuming there is no real data on that machine yet: stop MarkLogic, flush its Data directory, start MarkLogic, and revisit the Admin ui. That will restart the initialization, and you will have a new chance entering initial admin credentials..

HTH!

Comment: how to flush data directory of marklogic..please explain..I am new in the mark logic

Comment: Here is a one-liner for MacOS: https://gist.github.com/jmakeig/f51708ec2c89386abccd. It is the same steps for all operating systems, though you might need to check install docs to see where Data lives..