# Security Setup -- authentication error on Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

i've installed Marklogic just now and started the server-- all following the instructions on the site.

in "Security Setup" window at [this](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/installation/procedures#id_60220) 
stage, i got stuck-- didn't accept any username (admin) password i tried. a pop-up window keeps coming up asking me username&password, saying 
"http://localhost:8001/ requires a username and password."

i uninstalled Marklogic and installed again. ended up with the very same thing.

how did i manage to hit the cement wall the very first minute?

i saw [regarding installation of marklogic server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196575/regarding-installation-of-marklogic-server/) and [Forgot my admin username and password in MarkLogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803678/forgot-my-admin-username-and-password-in-marklogic) among some other useful discussions.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear to me from your description whether you went through the normal installation pages to create the security database and create an admin user. If you did that, but were unable to log in once installation completed, you likely mistyped your credentials at some point.

If you did not walk through those pages, but were instead just presented with a login prompt when you first visited http://localhost:8001/, then you either have a previous MarkLogic install or some other service is already using that port.

Uninstalling the package will get rid of the software, but leaves any previous install in /var/opt/MarkLogic. You can stop the server and remove that directory to clean out the previous install.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you hit 'Skip' on the screen for joining a cluster and are not just stuck there?